# I want to replace the old value in a CSV file, with a brand new entry

Tags: vb.net, csv

This is currently what  I currently occupy in my code. However I'm getting a error message which says, "No accessible'Replace' accepts this number of arguments.

```
 For x As Integer = 0 To liness.GetUpperBound(0)
                    liness(x) = liness(x).Replace(oldValue:=stdntyear)
                    IO.File.WriteAllLines("F:\Computing\Spelling Bee\stdnt&staffdtls.csv", liness)
                Next
```

Comment: Replace expects two arguments: old value (to be replaced) and new value (replacement); but your code includes just one.

Comment: Can't the old value(which is unknown) be replaced with a entered string? In this case stdntyear (variable)

Comment: The old value cannot be unknown. Otherwise how you would expect "Replace" to work? Randomly? Example: InputSTring = "1122334455" NewValue = 6; what should Replace do without knowing the old value? Guessing which original value you want to replace (1 or 2 or...)? Please, think carefully about what you want to accomplish before posting a question. The answer to your question is: add two arguments. If you need to rely only on one argument, it would mean that your algorithm (and thus your ideas on this implementation) is wrong; think about it and, eventually, post here a different question.

Comment: The 'oldvalue' was there as pseudo code. The 'oldvalue' will have a set value from a CSV file, and will be replaced by the new value entered.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion, I have now sorted it out.